# Is there a faster way to rewrite Time Stamp data?

Tags: python, datetime, optimization, time, timestamp

I am kind new in Python and would need some help to optimize my code. So my problem is this: I am dealing with many files with around 800,000 x 12 in size.

The first column is in Time Stamp format, divided by 5 seconds (so we should have 12 rows per minute). What happens is that I do not have the seconds in it, so I need to write a code to do so. This is how my raw data looks like.

```
0     2018-02-27 10:57:00
1     2018-02-27 10:57:00
2     2018-02-27 10:57:00
3     2018-02-27 10:57:00
4     2018-02-27 10:58:00
5     2018-02-27 10:58:00
6     2018-02-27 10:58:00
7     2018-02-27 10:58:00
8     2018-02-27 10:58:00
9     2018-02-27 10:58:00
10    2018-02-27 10:58:00
11    2018-02-27 10:58:00
12    2018-02-27 10:58:00
13    2018-02-27 10:58:00
14    2018-02-27 10:58:00
15    2018-02-27 10:58:00
16    2018-02-27 10:59:00
17    2018-02-27 10:59:00
18    2018-02-27 10:59:00
```

So after some reading, I found out that if I have the first and last time instant, I could create a time range dictionary with the date_range function, and then substitute my column (see code below). This works and it is fast, but only if I don't have missing data in the interval (and there is a lot of missing rows btw), since the number of rows created by the function will be different than the number of rows that I have.

```
start = df.iloc[0,0]
startstr = start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

finish = df.iloc[-1,0]
finishstr = finish.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

newdatetime = pd.date_range(startstr,finishstr, freq='5S')

df["Date_Timefixed"] = newdatetime
df = df.drop('Date_Time', axis=1)
```

After some thought, I was trying to create a new code using the logic of comparison between rows, and then using an iterator to calculate the seconds value. I tested this new approach in a small portion  (30 rows) and works fine. However, for a real 800,000 rows file is taking more than 30 minutes to finish.

```
i = 0
for row in range(len(df.index)):
    if i > 12:
        break
    else:
        if df.iloc[row,0] == df.iloc[row-1,0]:
            df.iloc[row-1,0] = df.iloc[row-1,0].replace(second=5*i)
            i += 1
        else:
            df.iloc[row-1,0] = df.iloc[row-1,0].replace(second=55)
            i = 0
```

So my question is: Is there a more efficient way to write the second approach? Or even more, could you help me think in a smarter way to solve this problem (rewrite timestamps that should be divided in 5 seconds interval?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, I am not a `pandas` expert so others might have a better way.

First let's get rid of all timestamps where it doesn't end with `00` since we want to create our own ranges.

```
grouped = df[df.ts.str.endswith(':00')].groupby('ts')

pd.concat([grouped.ts.apply(lambda group: pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range(start=group.min(), periods=12,freq='5S')))]).melt().value

0    2018-02-27 10:57:00
1    2018-02-27 10:57:05
2    2018-02-27 10:57:10
3    2018-02-27 10:57:15
4    2018-02-27 10:57:20
5    2018-02-27 10:57:25
6    2018-02-27 10:57:30
7    2018-02-27 10:57:35
8    2018-02-27 10:57:40
9    2018-02-27 10:57:45
10   2018-02-27 10:57:50
11   2018-02-27 10:57:55
12   2018-02-27 10:58:00
13   2018-02-27 10:58:05
14   2018-02-27 10:58:10
15   2018-02-27 10:58:15
16   2018-02-27 10:58:20
17   2018-02-27 10:58:25
18   2018-02-27 10:58:30
19   2018-02-27 10:58:35
20   2018-02-27 10:58:40
21   2018-02-27 10:58:45
22   2018-02-27 10:58:50
23   2018-02-27 10:58:55
24   2018-02-27 10:59:00
25   2018-02-27 10:59:05
26   2018-02-27 10:59:10
27   2018-02-27 10:59:15
28   2018-02-27 10:59:20
29   2018-02-27 10:59:25
30   2018-02-27 10:59:30
31   2018-02-27 10:59:35
32   2018-02-27 10:59:40
33   2018-02-27 10:59:45
34   2018-02-27 10:59:50
35   2018-02-27 10:59:55
Name: value, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```